# Problema de storage en login en angular

Tags: angular

Tengo una web Spa  con angular +api restfull en laravel la cual mediante un formulario estoy haciendo el login (Login con JWT).
Con este codigo lo que hago es recoger la respuesta del login, guardar el usuario como un objeto y almacenarlo en el Storage y guardar el token de autentificación.

```html
onSubmit(form){
    console.log(this.User);

    this._UserService.singup(this.User).subscribe(
      response => {
            //recoger token + guardar en storage
            this.authentication = response;
            localStorage.setItem('authentication', this.authentication);

            //recoher objeto del usuario + guardar en storage
            this._UserService.singup(this.User, true).subscribe(
              response => {
                  this.identity = response;
                  localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.identity));
              },
              error => {
               console.log(<any>error) ;
              }
            );
      },
      error => {
       console.log(<any>error) ;
      }
    );

  }
```

El problema viene que si por ejemplo pongo mal la contraseña mi api me devuele

```
{status: "error", code: "400", message: "Login ha fallado"}
```

El problema esque mi metodo onSumit del formulario de login cuando la contraseña falla y me devuelve el mensaje anterior, me lo guarda en el storage com la identidad del usuario y se activa la web como si fuera hecho login.Pero no consigo hacer que funcione.

Comment: ¿Y si pones un `if` para ver si hay un campo `status` con el valor `"error"`?

Comment: si al final lo resolví asi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final cómo dice Pablo lo resolví con un if

```html
onSubmit(form){
    console.log(this.User);
    this._UserService.singup(this.User).subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.status != 'error'){
                  this.status = 'success';
                  //recoger token + guardar en storage
                  this.authentication = response;
                  localStorage.setItem('authentication', this.authentication);

                  //recoher objeto del usuario + guardar en st
                  this._UserService.singup(this.User, true).subscribe(
                    response => {
                        this.identity = response;
                        localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.identity));

                        this._router.navigate(['/']);
                    });
          }else{
            this.status = 'error';
          }
      },
      error => {
       console.log(<any>error) ;
      }
    );
  }
```